# How do I modify Drupal's Admin Screens?

Tags: drupal-7, themes

I'm looking to edit Drupal's admin pages.

Some of the things I'm trying to achieve:

1. Remove is the the filter setting on the Content page/node/view. In other words, if I go to to the Content page and I filter by a certain type of node, then I leave that page, then come back, the filter setting is saved, I'd like it to reset each time I visit the Content page.
2. I would like to modify some of links associated with these pages, as an example on that Same Content page, the titles of the pages are linked to their 'front-end' views, I'd rather have them link to their 'edit' screens.

While I have been successful in modifying the front-end theme of Drupal, by editing the actual php files. I can't find the the same php files for the Admin theme. In our case we are using Seven (7.21). I've read something about views, and thought maybe the entire Admin theme is built as views, aka there no php files involved like the front-end theme has, but under the Views section I did not find any either. I'm still pretty new at this and coming from the Wordpress world, this is a Drupal is a lot different.

Answer (score 3):

The logic for that section of the admin area is at (from the public root):
/modules/node

Specifically "node.admin.inc"

That being said, I don't recommend editing core scripts, as they will be overwritten when you update the core.

You could explore making your [own module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules) to supplement that page, or your [own view](http://definitivedrupal.org/suggestions/creating-custom-administrator-view-content) or explore some pre-made modules, such as "[Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views)"

Answer (score 2):

Find de view displayed and go to its configuration :

1 - Edit configuration view like suggested here : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44440/how-to-remember-exposed-filter-choices

2 - Rewrite output views to rewrite link : field https://www.drupal.org/node/1578524

Another option is to create and use your own dashboard/views to achive like you want http://definitivedrupal.org/suggestions/creating-custom-administrator-view-content

also you can see contrib module : https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use that default content overview page at all. Make your own instead:

Make a page view (you have to install views module if you already did not: https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and use table layout. Make sure that page paths starts with "admin" so it will use admin theme. Also pay attention about permissions, so only specific set of users (admins) can use it.

For that view you can freely select what columns you what to show. You can also allow ordering by any column and action if you click on some field.

Use exposed filters to add filtering form, again add any filters you need. You can even set the form to use AJAX, to do auto-submit when some filter field is changed, include reset button and more. Also for every exposed filed you can select (at fields settings) should it remember it's value or not.

At end, edit admin menu and add your new page to it so it will look and act as default one but will offer much more functionality. You can even totally remove default one from the admin menu.

Views module is very powerful, not only for front-end but also for back-end content handling.